# How to structurally write different configurations of code for different number of variables

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, coding-style, structure

I am calibrating a bunch of parameters using any method (not important). But the number of parameters I choose to calibrate will be varied (anywhere from 1 to 4). If I wanted to calibrate 4 parameters, my code would look like:

```
def derivative(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1*1.1,p2,p3,p4)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1*0.9,p2,p3,p4)
    d1 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p1)
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2*1.1,p3,p4)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2*0.9,p3,p4)
    d2 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p2)
    
    #...
   
    return np.array([d1,d2,d3,d4])

def calibrating(old_params,a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    # some for loop, looping and updating the parameters 
    J = derivative(a,b,c,d,old_params[0],old_params[1],old_params[2],old_params[3])

    new_params = old_params + J


initial_guess = np.array([p1,p2,p3,p4])

calibrated_params =  calibrating(initial_guesses,a,b,c,d,0,0,0,0)
```

But sometimes I want `p1` and `p2` to be fixed. And my code would look something like:

```
def derivative(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    # d3 and d4 variable names aren't important. 
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3*1.1,p4)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3*0.9,p4)
    d3 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p3)
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4*1.1)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4*0.9)
    d4 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p4)
    
    return np.array([d3,d4])

def calibrating(old_params,a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    # some for loop, looping and updating the parameters 
    J = derivative(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,old_params[2],old_params[3])
    new_params = old_params + J

p1=2
p2=3
initial_guess = np.array([p3,p4])

calibrated_params =  calibrating(initial_guesses,a,b,c,d,p1,p2,0,0)
```

Is there a way this can be cleanly coded without coding every possible configuration? My initial idea was to put the fixed parameters in the initial_guess array as seen below, but would still need many different derivative configurations.

```
def derivative(a,b,c,d,old_params):
    # d3 and d4 variable names aren't important. 
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,old_params[0],old_params[1],old_params[2]*1.1,old_params[3])
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,old_params[2]*0.9,old_params[3])
    d3 = (du-dd) / (0.2*old_params[2])
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,old_params[0],old_params[1],old_params[2],old_params[3]*1.1)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,old_params[0],old_params[1],old_params[2],old_params[3]*0.9)
    d4 = (du-dd) / (0.2*old_params[3])
    
    return np.array([d3,d4])

def calibrating(old_params,a,b,c,d):
    # some for loop, looping and updating the parameters 
    J = derivative(a,b,c,d,old_params)
    new_params = old_params + J

p1=2
p2=3
initial_guess = np.array([p1,p2,p3,p4])

calibrated_params =  calibrating(initial_guesses,a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: Hello. If I understand correctly, you have a few relations between parameters, and you want the user to choose which parameter they specify, and then your function should calculate the values of the unspecified parameters using those relations?

Comment: @Stef yes, but when a parameter isn't being calibrated, it will be some fixed float, but it will be still required in the `my_func()` function

Comment: I have to say it's a bit hard to understand and answer your question. Sentences like *"I am calibrating a bunch of parameters using any method (not important)."* are extremely vague and don't really help to understand what is going on. Comments like `# d3 and d4 variable names aren't important.` only add to the confusion. Also, you posted two versions of a relatively long code with tons of variables without much explanation, and then you ask *"Is there a way this can be cleanly coded?"* and it's unclear what *"this"* means in that sentence.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def derivative(a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1*1.1,p2,p3,p4)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1*0.9,p2,p3,p4)
    d1 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p1)
    
    du = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2*1.1,p3,p4)
    dd = my_func(a,b,c,d,p1,p2*0.9,p3,p4)
    d2 = (du-dd) / (0.2*p2)
    
    #...
   
    return np.array([d1,d2,d3,d4])

def calibrating(old_params,a,b,c,d,p1,p2,p3,p4):
    # some for loop, looping and updating the parameters 
    J = derivative(a,b,c,d,old_params[0],old_params[1],old_params[2],old_params[3])

    new_params = old_params + J


initial_guess = np.array([p1,p2,p3,p4])

calibrated_params =  calibrating(initial_guesses,a,b,c,d,0,0,0,0)
```